# Having trouble with View Function in Django, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

It seems like I'm having trouble with my Django web application. I have implemented a save() function to allow users to create and save new encyclopedia entries, but when I try to submit a new entry, the application redirects to the "error.html" template instead of the "entry.html" template with the newly created entry. I have already checked the save() function and modified the if statement to properly check whether the new entry already exists before saving it. I have also added print statements to the save() and converter() functions to debug the issue, but I'm still unable to identify the root cause of the problem. Here's views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from . import util

from markdown2 import Markdown

import random

def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })


def New(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/new.html")

def save(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST.get('title','')
        content = request.POST.get('content', '')
        entry = util.list_entries()

        if title in entry:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/exists.html")
        else:
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return converter(request, title)



def Random1(request):
    entry = util.list_entries()
    rand_entry = random.choice(entry)

    return converter(request, rand_entry)

def converter(request, title):
    entry = util.list_entries()
    markdowner = Markdown()
    if title in entry:
        content = util.get_entry(title)
        data = markdowner.convert(content)
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "data": data
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")
    

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        input = request.POST.get('q', '')
        html = converter(request,input)

        entries = util.list_entries()
        if input in entries:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
                "data": html,
            })
        else:
            search_pages = []
            for entry in entries:
                if input in entry:
                    search_pages.append(entry)
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
                "entries": search_pages,
            })
```

Util.py:

```
import re

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage


def list_entries():
    """
    Returns a list of all names of encyclopedia entries.
    """
    _, filenames = default_storage.listdir("entries")
    return list(sorted(re.sub(r"\.md$", "", filename)
                for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".md")))


def save_entry(title, content):
    """
    Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
    content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
    it is replaced.
    """
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))


def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

Comment: Please ask *one* question at a time. Explain what the problem is with the current appraoch.

Comment: Share `list_entries` function from `util`.

Comment: Hi, I've added all the required code. Please take a look and let me know.